# Direct URL to a JSF bean action

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

Is there any way to get direct URL to a JSF bean action method?

Basically I want to be able to do the following:

```
<a href="/PA/faces/pageBeanAction">click</a>
```

And this should invoke a method in a JSF bean. Is it possible?

I'm using JSF 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the job in the constructor of the request scoped bean associated with the view behind the URL.

```
public class Bean {

    public Bean() {
        // Here.
    }

    // ...
}
```

As long as you've a `#{bean.something}` in the view, then the bean's constructor will be invoked.